# Actionscript -Need to generate color value in a loop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

Having a for loop say like

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) { 
   // need to generate color value for each i. 
    //need to set the color value for drawing rectangle dynamically
}
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what kind of color you want to generate. Also, are you drawing using the drawing api or on a bitmap?

Comment: Hi i am drawing using graphics.beginfill() method inside a sprite. Anyway I will be more specific next time. Pranav and Ptrick helped on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on Pranav Hosangadi's answer:

```
private function createColors(n:int):Array
{ 
  var colors:Array = [];

  for( var i= 0; i < n ; i++ )
  {   
    // for instance, but you could come up with
    // a variety of formulas , depending on what kind of spectrum 
    // you're looking for!
    var color:uint = 0xffffff * Math.random(); 

    // add your newly created color to the Array
    // you could also do : colors[i] = 0xffffff * Math.random();
    colors[i] = color;
  }

   return colors;
}


//after this you can generate your rectangles

private function createRectangles():void
{
    var colors:Array = createColors( 10 );

    for( var i= 0; i < colors.length ; i++ )
    { 
      var rect:Sprite = new Sprite();

      var g:Graphics=rect.graphics;
      g.beginFill(colors[i]);
      g.drawRect(10 * i , 10 * i, 100, 150); 
      g.endFill();

      this.addChild( rect );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

colours in ActionScript are specified using `uint`s

```
var myColor:uint=0xRRGGBB;
```

To draw a rectangle (in a `DisplayObject`)

```
var g:Graphics=this.graphics;
g.beginFill(0xcc0000); //Red fill
g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 150); //Rectangle at (10, 10) with size (100, 150)
g.endFill();
```